# Control constraints of a nested table of references in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, nested-table

I'm doing some Object-Relational stuff in oracle. I'm having problems with a nested table of references, in which I cannot control the PK as usual, so I have to create a trigger to control it.

The types are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_Persona AS OBJECT (
    id number(5),
    nombre varchar2(20),
    apellidos varchar2(30),
    dni varchar2(9),
    telefonos ListaTelefonos, 
    fecha_alta date,    
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getPID RETURN NUMBER    
)NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_HoraActividad AS OBJECT
(
    idact NUMBER(3),
    Hora_Inicio DATE,
    Dia VARCHAR2(10),
    Duracion NUMBER(4,2),
    ...
    Monitor REF Tipo_Monitor
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_Monitor_Horas AS TABLE OF REF Tipo_HoraActividad;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_Monitor UNDER Tipo_Persona
(
    Actividades Tipo_Monitor_Horas,
    Sueldo_Hora NUMBER(4,2),
    MEMBER FUNCTION sueldo return NUMBER,
    PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES (sueldo, WNDS)
);
/

-- Creation of Tables

...

CREATE TABLE Tabla_Monitor OF Tipo_Monitor
(
    constraint PK_MONITOR PRIMARY KEY(id),
    constraint UNIQUE_DNI_MONITOR UNIQUE(dni),
    dni NOT NULL,
    fecha_alta NOT NULL,
    nombre NOT NULL
)
NESTED TABLE Actividades STORE AS Actividades_Impartidas;

...
```

So now... my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_name
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Actividades_Impartidas
FOR EACH ROW

...
-- I can deref the :new row of Tipo_HoraActividad and check if
-- their values are NULL.  But I don't know how to control if
-- it exists any other ref within the current table pointing to
-- the same HoraActividad(unique constraint). My main problem is
-- that I cannot access to this current table (Actividades_Impartidas)
-- because it is a nested table of a concrete row of Tabla_Monitor.
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8135488196597 (it is certainly both credible and official)

Answer (score 0):

I myself looked for an answer for this a lot but couldn't find it. Visited the URL that Martin Drautzbug provided in that URL and my opinion changed about this question. You should not make things complicated just because you can. That's one of the foremost rules of database design- reduce anomalies for DML statements as much as possible.

It has been my personal experience that using nested tables as a table column just makes things more complicated and difficult to process with simple SQL statements. I read it [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8135488196597) and they confirm this. We try to denormalize database design for saving some amount of efforts by using nested tables but it just results into us putting more efforts trying to un-nest them all the time. Plus, it is difficult to enforce constraints on these nested tables.

One good solution would be to use separate tables instead of the nested tables and normalize as much as you can. If you are designing a real transactional database and going to do a lot of DML you should always escape the un-nesting of tables all the time.

Nested tables is a great option in PL/SQL where you have to bulk collect results from a query temporarily in a collection and process it. It is not the same with creating tables with nested table columns.

I am posting this URL again [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8135488196597) for you to visit for more details.